# Hidden files beginning with B

Tags: linux

I am currently doing an assessment and I am stuck on a question, it's "how do you modify the `ls -a` command so that it only shows hidden files beginning with B?" I have managed to find out how to show files beginning with B but not hidden files. I would really appreciate the help, thank you very much!

Comment: Well, hidden files usually begin with `.`, so I'm presuming the question actually means files that begin with `.B`, so you should be able to use that in your `ls`

Comment: A "hidden" file's name starts with `.`, therefore, there are no hidden files with names starting with `B`.    ;-)

Comment: Originally the authors of `ls` wanted to not display `..` and `.`. So they did a quick hack: If file-name does not start with a `.` then display it. This passed all the tests (they missed out some tests e.g. `...`, `.hello`). So they deployed it. The users then discovered that they could hide files, by starting them with a `.`. Eventually it was documented, and thus official behaviour.

Comment: Does your question mean “show files if and only if they are hidden and then start with a `.B`;>". OR “show files if not hidden or starts with a `.B`” (i.e. “only show hidden files if they begin with `B`”)?

Answer (score 2):

You can list all hidden files starting with "B" with the following command:

```
ls -a .B*
```

Comment: you don't even need the `-a`!

Comment: `echo .B*` perhaps? :)

Comment: You do need a `-d` though. Or it will show content of directories, if file is a directory.